# .NET 6 Service: Serialization and deserialization of 'System.DateOnly' instances are not supported

Tags: c#, aws-lambda, .net-6.0, system.text.json

I am developing NET 6 Web Service (+Startup)
My controller

```
public async PutDirectorStr(string jsonstr)
{
Director? director = new Director();
 try
 {
     var options = new JsonSerializerOptions
     {
        IncludeFields = true,
        PropertyNameCaseInsensitive = true
     };

     director = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Director>(director_str, options);
     var sr = await _directorService.PutDirector(director, cancellationToken);
     if (sr.StatusCode < 0) { return BadRequest(sr.StatusText); }
}

 public class Director: IDirector
 {
     [JsonPropertyName("Id")]
     public int Id { get; set; }
     [JsonPropertyName("Parent_id")]
     public int Parent_id { get; set; }
     [JsonPropertyName("FirstName")]
     public string FirstName { get; set; } = string.Empty;
     [JsonPropertyName("LastName")]
     public string LastName { get; set; } = string.Empty;
     [JsonPropertyName("BirthDate")]
     public DateOnly BirthDate { get; set; }
}
```

My Startup

```
...
services.AddControllers()
  .AddJsonOptions(options =>
  {
      options.JsonSerializerOptions.Converters.Add(new DateOnlyJsonConverter());
  });
```

It works ok, But when I use json containing DateOnly object

```
{
  "id": 201,
  "parent_id": 21349,
  "firstName": "Monkey",
  "lastName": "Donley",
  "birthDate": "2023-09-18"
}
```

I receve an exception

```
Serialization and deserialization of 'System.DateOnly' instances are not supported.
```

I have added the class and call as recommended there but the same exception

[System.NotSupportedException: Serialization and deserialization of 'System.DateOnly' instances are not supported](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74246482/system-notsupportedexception-serialization-and-deserialization-of-system-dateo)

If I remove the birthdate field from the json then it works ok.
How to fix it?

Comment: The error is clear. In .NET 6 serialization of DateOnly and TimeOnly wasn't yet supported. This was added in .NET 7

Comment: What does the `Director` class look like? What does your code look like after you have followed the link you show above?

Comment: Is this a *new* application? In that case you should probably target .NET 8, the next Long-Term-Support version that will be released in November 2023. The latest [.NET 8 RC1 release has a go-live license](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/announcing-dotnet-8-rc1/), which means it's supported in production, the API is stable and only bug fixes will be added before November.

Comment: And how to fix it? My NET 6 service finally is Lambda, AWS supports NET6.

Comment: @DavidG Updated the start msg.

Comment: Does AWS support .NET 7? In that case that's the best option. Otherwise the duplicate shows how to create custom converters.

Comment: I have made as recommended by link above but again the exception.

Comment: That's not shown in the question. There's no `DateOnlyJsonConverter`, `TimeOnlyJsonConverter`  or any call to `JsonSerializerOptions.Converters.Add`. In any case, [AWS Lambda does support .NET 7](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/building-serverless-net-applications-on-aws-lambda-using-net-7/)

Comment: You have still not shown how you are using the `DateOnlyJsonConverter` from the other question.

Comment: If you are manually deserialising, then the `AddJsonOptions` isn't going to have any effect, you need to update your `options` object like this: `options.Converters.Add(new DateOnlyJsonConverter());`

Comment: @DavidG yes,  I  deserialize JSON manually in the controller method. I have added the options.Converters.Add  just in the method as you recommended. Will check how it works

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos it ok, but I read it "Lambda has not released a managed runtime for .NET 7, since it is not a long-term support (LTS) release." and did not port my project to NET7. May be I can do it?